# How can I identify if there is text?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to identify if there is text on canvas in tkinter.

```
import tkinter  
c = tkinter.Canvas(width=500, height=500)  
def actionOne():  
      c.delete(text)                          #here I have to identify if there is any text  
      text = c.create_text(250, 400, text="Hi")  
def actionTwo():  
      c.delete(text)                     # Here again
      c.create_text(250, 400, text="Bye")
```

Can anybody help me please? I have to find out if there is text to avoid an UnboundLocal Error.

I am looking forward for answers. Thanks!

Comment: Would using `global text` work for you?

Comment: Finding out if there is text or not is completely unrelated to an UnboundLocal error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access and update the `text` variable from the global scope, do so with `global`. If `text` is not defined in that scope, you can catch the `NameError` exception raised.

```
def actionOne():
    global text
    try:
        c.delete(text)
    except NameError:
        pass
        text = c.create_text(250, 400, text="Hi")
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple explanation. It's useful and great!

Answer (score 2):

If `text` is global, you can use `if text not in globals()` to check if text is defined. Furthermore, you can use `if globals().get('text')` which will return `False` if `text` is either empty or not defined:

```
text = ''

if not globals().get('text'):
    print(False)

# False
```

You can do the same thing with `locals()` inside a function

```
def actionOne():
  if isinstance(locals().get('text'), str()) and len(locals().get('text'))>1:  
      c.delete(text)                            
  text = c.create_text(250, 400, text="Hi")
```

Comment: to be more specific you could make sure it's a non-empty string via `if isinstance(text, six.string_types) and len(text) > 0: . . . `

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer useful and helps me!